# Build with moverio BT-2000 library

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, epson

I'm trying to develop apps for EPSON Moverio BT-2000.

I'm new to android studio and I don't understand why I can't use some methods from a library which I have imported (correctly, I supposed).

So, I have add my lib in a folder name libs, right click on it, add as Library.

I checked in builds.gradle

```
   dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile files('libs/H725Ctrl.jar') // this lib
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

    }
```

Moreover, I can use some elements (Methods, String definitions etc..) but some not. I don't understand why and how it's possible.

If it's necessary I can publish my source code.

Have you some ideas.?

Thanks.

Franck

NB: the lib I use is depreciated by android

NB2: Exemple

```
        Camera.Parameters params = l_pCamera.getParameters(); 
// I can do this and getParameters() works
        List<String> Supported = params.getSupportedEpsonCameraModes(); 
//I can't invoke getSupportedEpsonCameraModes() or methods are in the same file
```

Answer (score 1):

I contacted EPSON and they said it's a common problem.
So they send me a pdf which indicate how solve the problem..

It's strange..

NB the content of the PDF: sorry for the presentation but it will be helpful for someone..

```
1/2
Remark for using Android Studio
In case of using BT-2000 SDK with Android Studio, there may happen to have a failure during a build process. It may cause the conflict of the name between standard SDK and Epson expanded SDK. It is happened especially with “android.hardware.Camera” class.
It may resolve a failure with following action.
1． Sore H725Ctrl.jar at designated folder which is created by user like C:\Users\<user name\AndroidStudioProjects\<application name>\app\libs
2． Set change of gradle by selecting “Sync Project with Gradle Files” button which is located upper of Android Studio screen.
3． Open “build.gradle” for specified project with specified application name by selecting left side button on Android Studio screen. Then edit with following contents.
allprojects { repositories { jcenter() } gradle.projectsEvaluated { tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { options.compilerArgs.add('-Xbootclasspath/p:C:/Users/<user name>/AndroidStudioProjects/<application name>/app/libs/H725Ctrl.jar') } } }
4． Execute “Clean Project” then “Make Project” in Android Studio Build menu.
5． If error occurs in Make project process, end Android Studio and restart it.
2/2
6． There may still remain several name conflicts with Android standard API like “getSupportedEpsonCameraModes()”. Ignore and “run application” to set it into target BT-2000.
[ Caution ]
It works temporally with following action;
Open
C:\Users\<user name>\AndroidStudioProjects\<application name>\app\app.iml
Move line of
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="H725Ctrl" level="project" />
to upper line of
<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android API 23 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />
This will help H725Ctrl.jar to be higher priority, however performing rebuild function will affect to reset name conflict issue.
Object which is performed build function already works well.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's weird. Epson tries to override some Android specific classes in their jar:

```
android.hardware.Camera 
android.hardware.Camera.Parameters
```

These classes are part of the Android SDK (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html). I do not know Epson would like to achieve, if they bundle the classes with their SDK. Maybe you could change the packagename in the H725Ctrl.jar to something like

```
com.epson.hardware
```

with JarJar (https://github.com/shevek/jarjar)?

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not familiar with Jarjar. Changing the name of the package can really resolve the problem ..?

Comment: I do not know. It may be a solution. I never used this sdk. Maybe you should contact Epson support.

Comment: I don't uderstand how to use JarJar.. Have you some quick advices ..,?

Comment: @Franck_Cordu did you get anywhere with this issue? Starting to work with the Moverio and trying to gather as much info as possible...

Comment: I dont know if EPSON have fix the problem. I'm not working on Moverio Right now. But if you want to use the EPSON library you have to modifie something in the gradle file. I can send you a pdf from EPSON if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your build.gradle file. The problem could be that the Moverio Camera class uses the same namespace as the Android sdk and there is an ordering issue

```
   allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }

    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs.add('-Xbootclasspath/p:C:/Source/EPSONProBT-2000ServiceMaintenance/app/libs/H725Ctrl.jar')
    }
}
```

}